# MVP not implementing Interface method

Tags: c#, asp.net, interface, mvp

I'm new to MVP design pattern so i'm following [this guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31210/Model-View-Presenter#MVPModelViewPresenterthesolution)‏

So I'm trying to recreate the guide for a `LoginModule` (just for trying out the new pattern). Now the thing is i do everything the same as in the guide, but still i'm running into Interface implementation issues. Ill attach my code below:

**Presenter class**

```
public class UserPresenter
{
    AuthenticateView iObjAuthView;
    public void add(AuthenticateView ObjAuthView)
    {
        iObjAuthView = ObjAuthView;
    }

    public void Authenticate(User _model)
    {
        if (_model.UName == "" && _model.UPassword == "")
        {
            iObjAuthView.ResponseOnAuthenticate(AuthEnums.Authorized);
        }
        else if (_model.UName == "" && _model.UPassword != "")
        {
            iObjAuthView.ResponseOnAuthenticate(AuthEnums.InCorrectPassWord);
        }
        else
        {
            iObjAuthView.ResponseOnAuthenticate(AuthEnums.UserNotFound);
        }
    }
}
```

**Interface class**

```
public interface AuthenticateView
{
      void ResponseOnAuthenticate(AuthEnums _authEnum);
}
```

**UIpage(aspx page)**

```
public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page, AuthenticateView
{
    private UserPresenter objPresenter = new UserPresenter();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        objPresenter.add(this);
    }

    protected void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        objPresenter.Authenticate(new StockBO.User(EmailBox.Text, PasswordBox.Text));
    }

    public void Auth(AuthEnums _auth)
    {
        Label3.Text = _auth.ToString();
    }
}
```

On the UI page the compiler throws an Error that i don't implement the `ResponseToAuthenticate` method defined in the interface. So for the last or so I'm trying to figure out whats wrong.

Is it the guide that is wrong or is it me that is doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, you're bound to the contract that implementing the `interface AuthenticateView` implies.

Add your method `ResponseOnAuthenticate(authEnum) { //... }` to `class login` and you should be fine.

On a side note: use Pascal casing for class names (by convention)